Tu's Differential Geometry. Definition 18.2 of tensor product
In Tu's differential geometry, section 18.1 the definition of tensor product is provided.
Specifically

Let $V, W$ be left R-modules. To define their tensor product, first construct the free R-module $\text{Free}(V \times W)$ whose basis is the set of all ordered pairs $(v,w) \in V \times W$. This means that an element of $\text{Free}(V \times W)$ is uniquely a finite linear combination of elements of $V \times W$:
$$
\sum r_i(v_i,w_i) \;\;\;, r_i \in R, (v_i,w_i) \in V \times W.
$$
In $\text{Free}(V \times W)$, consider the $R$-submodule $S$ spanned by all elements of the form
$$
\begin{array}{c}
(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1,w) - (v_2,w), \\
(v, w_1 + v_2) - (v,w_1) - (v,w_2), \\
(rv,w) - r(v,w) \\
(v,rw) - r(v,w)
\end{array}
$$

for all $v_1,v_2,v \in V$, $w_1,w_2,w \in W$ and $r \in R$
Then we have the following definition

Definition 18.2: The tensor product $V \otimes_R W$ of two R-modules $V$ and $W$ is the quotient R-module $\text{Free}(V \times W)$ where $S$ is the R-submodule spanned by the elements of the form (18.1) (the equations above). When it is understood that the coefficient ring is $R$, we write simply $V \otimes W$.

Question 1. I need a clarification on the meaning of spanned in this context. In the context of vector spaces for example if $V$ is a vector space and $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in V$ then we normally define the subspace spanned by $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ as
$$
\text{Span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = \left\{ \alpha_1 v_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n : \alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n \in \mathbb{F}\right\}
$$
here $\mathbb{F}$ is the scalar field of the vector space $V$.
I would extend this to a module by assuming that $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ belong to the ring $R$ of the module.
However I am having a bit of a hard time to figure out how to write the $S$ as a spanned space. Can anybody clarify?
Question 2. Similar as 1 but for quotient space. If $X$ is a vector space and $Y$ is a subspace we define the quotient space $V / W = \left\{ v + W : v \in V \right\}$. For modules I would define exactly in the same way. Therefore by definition 18.2 it should be
$$
V \otimes_R W = \text{Free}(V \times W) / S = \left\{ (v,w) + S : (v,w) \in \text{Free}(V \times W) \right\}
$$
Is it correct?

Your intuition on both points is correct. As for how to write $S$ as a submodule spanned by the elements in question, you basically already have it down:
$$
    S = \left\{\sum_{i = 1}^k r_i \alpha_i \mid k \geq 1, \alpha_i \in A, r_i \in R \text{ for all }i\right\} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \langle a \mid a \in A \rangle
$$
where
\begin{align}
    A &= \{(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w) \mid v_1, v_2 \in V, w \in W\} \\
    &\quad\cup \{(v, w_1 + w_2) - (v, w_1) - (v, w_2) \mid v \in V, w_1, w_2 \in W\} \\
    &\quad\cup \{(rv, w) - r(v, w) \mid r \in R, v \in V, w \in W\} \\
    &\quad\cup \{(v, rw) - r(v, w) \mid r \in R, v \in V, w \in W\} \\
\end{align}
i.e. $S$ consists of all finite linear combinations of elements in $A$, just as you would have in the linear algebra setting in the case that $R$ is a field.
For point 2 there is nothing more to say; what you wrote is correct.

Out of curiosity, what is the reason to define $A$ as such? is it because it makes later math work?

@user8469759 $A$ is set up in a way so that $\operatorname{Free}(V \times W) / S$ has the universal property of the tensor product. If this is unfamiliar to you, you should look up a proof of this (in a (multi-)linear algebra text if you're uncomfortable with $R$ being a ring as opposed to a field; neither construction nor proof really change), and you'll see why one wants to define $A$ like this.

Perhaps as a broad overview, the univ. prop. of $V \otimes_R W$ roughly states that any bilinear map $V \times W \to Z$ gives rise to a linear map $V \otimes_R  W \to Z$. With this in mind, the elements of $A$ should look familiar: $(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w) \in A$ is to say that $(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w) = 0$ in the quotient, i.e. $(v_1 + v_2, w) =  (v_1, w)  + (v_2, w)$ holds in $V \otimes_R W$ (for all $v_1, v_2, w$), but this should look familiar: It's one of the conditions of what it means to be a bilinear map!

So the idea boils down to roughly the following: Any function of sets $V \times W \to Z$ gives a linear map $\operatorname{Free}(V \times W) \to Z$. But I don't want any function, I just want bilinear ones. A bilinear map is a map of sets with certain constraints, so how do I model these constraints on $\operatorname{Free}(V \times W)$? Exactly by writing them all out (this gives the elements of $A$), and then linearizing them (this gives $S$), and then taking the quotient. :)

Those proofs are in the book. But normally textbooks just spit out theorems without giving too much rationale behind them.

@user8469759 Another reason to perhaps go and look at a linear algebra text. I haven't worked with Tu, but the construction is pretty much bog standard and many authors outside of linear algebra probably assume that you've seen something like this already. Differential Geometry textbooks in particular are somewhat known for this in particular (Lee is about the same level of detail here); and why shouldn't they: after all they're not books on linear algebra...

Thanks for the lovely comments and answer. Very helpful.
